# Python 3 how to UPDATE TIMESTAMPTZ?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

Please help update table with column type TIMESTAMPTZ.

Table like this

```
table(
            table_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            table_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
            last_update TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now(),
            table_link VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
            table_tracking BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
            url VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL            
        )
```

Code for update table

```
cur.execute("SET TIMEZONE='US/Pacific'; SELECT Now()")
time_db = cur.fetchall()

last_update = time_db[0][0]

        cur.execute("""
            UPDATE table
            SET
                last_update = {},
                table_tracking = {}
            WHERE id = {};
        """.format(last_update, tracking, id))
```

error.args in console

```
('syntax error at or near "10"\nLINE 5: last_update = 2017-07-28 10:17:55.523070')
```

Comment: If you have `last_update TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()` you don't need to specify that column in `SET`. The whole point of `DEFAULT` is that you can omit setting it?

Comment: You really shouldn't format your query string manually. The [`cur.execute`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) method is capable of escaping your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `2017-07-28 10:17:55.523070` is interpreted as an arithmetic expression - `2017 - 7 - 28 == 1982`. When it gets to the `10:17:55.523070` part, the parser has not idea what to do with it.

In order to have it interpreted as a `TIMESTAMPZ` value, you need to escape it like `'2017-07-28 10:17:55.523070'`. However, doing this manually is a bad idea for various reasons. Your database connection package should do it for you:

```
cur.execute("""
    UPDATE table
    SET
        last_update = %(last_update)s,
        table_tracking = %(table_tracking)s
    WHERE id = %(id)s;
    """,
    {
        "last_update": last_update,
        "table_tracking": tracking,
        "id": id,
    }
)
```

More information in the [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters)